# How do I get entries in a quick list to open in their own window?

Tags: unity, quicklists

I've created a few custom apps .eg facebook, google plus. I want them to open in ther own window instead of google chromes window (the white arrow showing open applications on the unity launcher). Can anyone help me do this?

Answer (score 1):

Actually this is a bug but these days it has been fixed, try to update your sistem. Then click on a web app in Chrome and choose Open in a window.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/692462